# View any type of File as a image

Tags: flutter, image, file

I want to view a file, almost like a image using the ImageNetwork. Save it on Firebase storage and view the url.  The problem is viewing any file that is not a image, get a blank image network.

Uplaod a word document and view it in a container like a image

Tried converting all file types to png but had no success

when I upload a document that is not a png /svg/jpg

[image]

Comment: "Upload a word document and view it in a container like a image", rendering a file, especially something as complex as document isn't that trivial

Comment: @Martheen I tried thad but still doesnt show, could you give an example of this

Comment: It looks like you didn't understand at all what Martheen wrote. Nowhere did they mention anything to try. They are merely stating that it's a very complex issue and there's no simple answer to it